# MySQL "Incorrect DATE value" in SELECT query inside WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL version: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

[image: error screenshot]

When running sample query:

```
SELECT *  FROM `redacted-tbl` 
WHERE `redacted-col` = 'some-invalid-date' 
ORDER BY `redacted-col`  DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

data structure: `redacted-col` DATE

I'm getting `#1525 - Incorrect DATE value: 'some-invalid-date'` error.

Now I understand that `'some-invalid-date'` is definitely not a valid mysql date format. I understand that the error is expected behavior **if it's an INSERT or UPDATE query**.

But why do I get such error on **SELECT query**? Previous version of mysql didn't throw such error for SELECT query (only for INSERT/UPDATE).

Also, how do I turn off this error for SELECT-ing DATE column? Is there any mysql flags to disable such check?

Edit (added from my comment):

In my opinion, there are good reasons to allow comparison of non-valid-date-string with `DATE` columns:

- querying with `WHERE mydatecol > '2015'` to get all date that is after '2015-01-01'
- even better, I can just pass user inputted date as filter (sanitized and parameter-bind-ed of course): `WHERE mydatecol > ?`,

  - if user enter `2015` then it will become shorthand for user who cares only to get all records after 2015
  - if user enter `2015-04`, then it will become shorthand for user who want records after 2015 month 04/April)
  - if user enter `2015-04-15` (normal/valid mysql date string), then app will display records after 2015 month 04/April date 15
- without this "non-date-validated comparison", I would have to write more application code just to check if the user inputted valid date or not, e.g.:

  - if the input format is 2015 then I have to change it into 2015-01-01,
  - else if the input format is 2015-04 then I have to change it into 2015-04-01,
  - else if the input format is 2015-04-15 then it's valid,
  - else it's not valid and throw error (or just output current date/default date or just show 'no entry matched your search criteria')

Comment: `WHERE redacted-col = 'some-invalid-date'` <-- it does not even make sense to compare a date column against a text string literal.  Why were you doing this to begin with, and what is the goal here?

Comment: `redacted-col` is a date column, if you want to compare values, they have to be of the same datatype, so the string is implicitly converted to a date (and fails). I don't know mysql, but I'm quite certain all mysql versions would throw this error.

Comment: in older mysql (where such comparison works), I often do this (maybe it's a bad practice idk): ```WHERE mydatecol > '2015'``` to get all date that is after '2015-01-01'

Comment: even better, I can just pass user inputted date as filter (sanitized and parameter-bind-ed of course) like this: ```WHERE mydatecol > ?```, so the user can just enter ```2015``` (shorthand for user who cares only to get all records after 2015), or the user can enter ```2015-04``` (for user who want records after 2015 month 04/April), or the user can enter ```2015-04-15``` (for detailed user who want records after 2015 month 04/April date 15)

Comment: without this "non-date-validated comparison", I would have to write more application code just to check if the user inputted valid date or not (e.g.: if the input format is ```2015``` then I have to change it into ```2015-01-01```, else if the input format is ```2015-04``` then I have to change it into ```2015-04-01```, else if the input format is ```2015-04-15``` then it's valid, else it's not valid and throw error (or just output current date/default date)

Comment: If you want to know a bit more about what is going on 'under-the-hood' with any of those queries, then you can always execute EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query], followed by SHOW WARNINGS (at least for older versions - the syntax may have changed in 8+; I can't remember)

Comment: @Strawberry ```EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT *  FROM `redacted-tbl` 
WHERE `redacted-col` = 'some-invalid-date' 
ORDER BY `redacted-col`  DESC LIMIT 0, 25
 ``` results: ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-date.html

Comment: Cast `mydatecol` to a string to perform the comparison. An easy way to do it is with CONCAT(): `WHERE CONCAT(mydatecol) > '2015'`

Comment: I was really talking about your other queries

Comment: @forpas nice, casting to string worked. But it kind of strange to write ```$query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(redacted-col)"), "LIKE", '%'.$request->mysearchdate.'%');``` instead of ```$query->where("redacted-col"), "LIKE", '%'.$request->mysearchdate.'%');``` in laravel. Maybe it's better to write ```CAST(redacted-col AS CHAR)``` instead?

Comment: Anything that works is fine. It's less typing with concat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The text of this answer was originally written by forpas https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas ]

You can cast `mydatecol` to a string to perform the comparison. An easy way to do it is with CONCAT():

`WHERE CONCAT(mydatecol) > '2015'`

or with cast:

`WHERE CAST(redacted-col AS CHAR) > 2015`